# How to get a list of Models in NDB Datastore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I would like to programmticaly delete all data in the Datastore.

In order to do that I need to loop over all the models and for each one delete all the model's entities.

So how can I programmatically get a list of all Models in the NDB Datastore?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [metadata](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/metadata). I needed the same myself so here is a full delete function for all models. This should work for up to several thousand entities per model:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.ext.ndb import metadata

kinds = metadata.get_kinds()
for kind in kinds:
    if kind.startswith('_'):
        pass  # Ignore kinds that begin with _, they are internal to GAE
    else:
        q = ndb.Query(kind=kind)
        keys = q.fetch(keys_only=True)

        # Delete 1000 entities at a time.
        for i in range(len(keys) / 1000 + 1):
            portion = keys[i*1000: i*1000+1000]
            ndb.delete_multi(portion)
```